# Different way of showing and hiding certain elements

Tags: javascript, html

I made a javascript aim train app that contains a menu. When I click play, I hide the elements of the menu and show the elements of the game... I was wondering if there was a more correct way of doing this without doing visibility hidden.

https://codepen.io/miguelserdeira/pen/oNEZRMj

This is an example of the part of the code that I want to change. Perhaps when I click play it should direct me to another page with the game? Thanks.

```
 //Shows the elements that should be visible or hidden
    imgTarget.style.visibility = "visible";
    startBtn.style.visibility = "hidden";
    timeText.style.visibility = "hidden";
    timeSlider.style.visibility = "hidden";
    targets.style.visibility = "hidden";
    sizeImg.style.visibility = "hidden";
    aviso.style.visibility = "visible";
    valor.style.visibility = "hidden";
    valor2.style.visibility = "hidden";
    valor3.style.visibility = "hidden";
    hits.style.visibility = "visible";
```

Comment: Wrap the menu and game elements into own elements, and toggle `display: none/block` of the wrappers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Example:

```
var startBtn = document.getElementById("comecar");
```

Is currently hidden with

```
startBtn.style.visibility = "hidden";
```

Try this instead:

```
$("#comecar").hide();
```

and to show it:

```
$("#comecar").show();
```

You can also chain elements together to hide them all in one line, like so:

```
$("#element1, #element2, #element3, #element4").hide();
```

Remove all of the visibility assignments.  That leaves the HTML element in place and masks the content, whereas the jQuery hiding removes the element